# Difference between var=$http and return $http

Tags: angularjs, http, resolve

I am trying to understand the difference between those two http calls in my factory:

```
One: function(code) {
       return $http.get('api/team/' + code)
         .then(function(resp) {
            return resp.data;
          });
        }
     }
```

And

```
Two: function(code) {
       var promise = $http.get('api/team/' + code);
        promise.then(function(resp) {
          return resp.data;
        });
          return promise;
     }
```

If I use `Two` in `resolve` in `config`:

```
resolve: {
   testt: ['$route','MyService',
          function($route, MyService) {            
          return MyService.Two($route.current.params.code);
          }]
}
```

Then I can see the data in my `ng-view`. If I use `One`, I dont see the data in `ng-view`.

My controller:

```
.controller('TeamDetailsCtrl',
           ['MyService','testt',
             function(MyService,testt) {
                var self = this;
                self.team = testt.data;
}]);
```

So, what is the difference?
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One: When `$http.get()` is done, it'll resolve and continue into the `then`. This returns another promise, filled with the result of the then function `result.data`. One returns the second promise.

Two: Returns the *original* promise from `$http.get()` with the result `result`, (in which you haven't transformed result into result.data). The correct syntax for two could be:

```
Two: function(code) {
   var promise = $http.get('api/team/' + code);
    var promise2 = promise.then(function(resp) {
      return resp.data;
    });
      return promise2;
 }
```

Comment: In one you return result.data (for instance: `{teamName: 'team', teamMembers: [member1, member2]}`). In two you return result (for instance: `{data: {teamName: 'team', teamMembers: [member1, member2]}}`. Change to `self.team = testt;` - one will work but two will fail.

Comment: Good answer. In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/edt3codu/) you can see the differences. The fiddle code is simplified (with-out the parameter code).

Comment: @JesseBuitenhuis But, if I would use `$q.defer()` in my factory, how should I wright my `resolve` `testt` call?

Comment: The same: `serviceCall: function() { var promise = $q.defer(); doSomethingAsync().then(function() $q.resolve(dataToPassToResolve); }); return promise; };`

Comment: Like this? getTeams: function() {
          var defer = $q.defer();
           $http.get('api/team')
          .then(function(resp){
            defer.resolve(resp.data);
          },
           function(resp){
            defer.reject(resp);
           });
          return defer.promise;
        }

Comment: But how should i write the function `testt` in resolve?

Answer (score 1):

`One` returns a promise, which will eventually return `resp.data`.

If you use `One`, `resp.data === testt` in your controller. `testt.data` doesn't work because `resp.data.data` doesn't work.

If you want to use `One`, change `self.team = testt.data` to `self.team = testt`.